# Android Scroll View Not Working?

Tags: xml, android-layout, scrollview

I am using simple Navigation theme on android studio, in this template contentmain.xml file I need to add the custom layout design on it, it will not scrolling , once landscape mode is change, design cannot be scrolled.

Below is the code for content-main.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.techinfoworld.gymfitnessworkoutinstructions.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar">
        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/gym1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:background="@android:drawable/spinner_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/abs_workout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/butt_workout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favourites"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/arm_workout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/full_workout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/share"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/leg_workout"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/workout_tips"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rate"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:text="Workout Daily to Get Fit GYM Body !!! "
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your layout in a `ScrollView` tag in order to get a scrolling behaviour.

[look here for more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: And the `ScrollView` just accepts one child view, so wrap all your components inside of a Linear/Relative layout :)

Comment: Myself beginner, can you re-modify the code and send back to me, its possible for you ? i need the same layout design, please can you help me ? @appyx